# How can I find joint probability of a bayesian network for three continuous random variables

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, probabilistic-programming

[Bayesian Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXopg.png)

For a network like the above directed graph, how do I find joint probability of three continuous random variables A,B,C.

Answer (score 0):

With [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

> P(A,B,C) = P(C | A,B) * P(A,B)
>
> = P(C | A,B) * P(A) * P(B)        (because A and B are independent)

Comment: How do I find probabilities (and conditional probabilities) if I have the data(A,B,C) which is continuous? @kutschkem

Comment: @RävîńdêrReddy I know more about discrete distributions, but I think the process would look like: 1. decide on a distribution that you assume (for example, gaussian) 2. fit distribution parameters to your data (for example, mean and standard derivation)